# How to identify floating button using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I came up in a scenario where I have floating button to identify. There is two buttons, Save and Cancel. When I am on top of the page buttons are like in a floating panel and once I scroll down and reach the bottom of the page then button will be fixed. So both cases I have two different identifier to identify the buttons. I am using the below code to scroll down.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

My question is, when I scroll down, how to know I reached the end of the page or not? Because I cannot scroll like unlimited time right? Once I reached the bottom of the page I can stop scrolling and check for the fixed button element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll to the end of the page using JavaScript as pointed out in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715670/1106708) answer. Here is the code snippet:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

This works fine *unless* you have content load as you scroll down (i.e. lazy loading). If that is the case, I would scroll to the bottom until a condition is met. This condition could be your "floating" element is Displayed.